# Properly embed javascript into WP (using function.php) - doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, javascript, ajax

It seems that my contact form's ajax javascript and the custom.js that I'm using for my drop-down navigation are interfering with each other.
The contact form's ajax fuction will only work properly if I won't call the "custom.js" in the header.
Furthermore I've had troubles using some jquery sliders, too, because something seemed to be interfering and I think that custom.js might be the cause.
I just copied it from another theme and tried to implement it into my theme, but apparently that wasn't such a good idea.
This has been a problem for months now. If only I knew how to fix that conflict, I have to admit that I know nothing about javascript!

[Here's](http://www.zoomingjapan.com) my website and here's my current header.php: http://pastebin.com/XhwqAGBt
This is the custom.js: http://pastebin.com/A9ZRySra

I need to get this sorted out no matter what, but I really can't do it on my own as my knowledge about javascript is non-existent, so please help me out a little!
I'll try hard to figure things out on my own, but I need a little help here, please!

EDIT4: I deleted my previous edits as it's getting too much to read and it wasn't that relevant anymore. I've been working on this almost the whole night and I just don't get it. Somebody who knows a bit about javascript, PLEASE help me out a little here.

I'm trying to get rid of all the javascript calls in my header.php and put them into my function.php instead as I heard that's better to do?!
So, what looked like this in my header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/Century_Gothic_400-Century_Gothic_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/javascript/custom.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to put into my function.php which looks like this right now:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
 // Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
 wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufon-yui.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_register_script('century_font', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Century_Gothic_400-Century_Gothic_700.font.js', array('jquery', 'cufon-yui'));

wp_enqueue_script('custom');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.form');
wp_enqueue_script('cufon-yui');
wp_enqueue_script('century-font');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Apart from the custom.js nothing else is working!! The cufon-yui etc.! Am I calling them incorrectly? I'm also not sure about the "jquery.form.js". Do I have to register it first? Should I call the WP "jquery-form" instead?!

EDIT: Additional information:
When I leave the custom.js in the function.php and put the other scripts back into the header, both: the navigation dropdown menu (custom.js) and the contact form (jquery.form + jquery 1.4.2) work perfectly fine.
I tried to put the javascript in the contact.php to "no.conflict" mode, but then the contact form stopped working properly again. I really don't get it!!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you have two versions of jQuery loading, and your lightbox js is using `$` instead of `jQuery`. search this site for how to properly enqueue javascript in your theme.

Comment: I read about it and I think I kind of got it but there's still a problem (see my edit).

Comment: I did everything I could. I tried various code snippets, always the same outcome. I don't know what's still going wrong. I also checked the .js files and they both call jquery in no-conflict mode.

Comment: Please do not put things like "unresolved" in title, it is messy and not in line with site's mechanics.

Comment: I see, didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the jQuery script is loaded in no conflict mode. I noticed that you have in you header.php the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Adding jQuery like this, will override (if the page works) the wp_enqueue_script('jquery').

If you load jQuery like this, you need to activate the noConflict mode, as explained [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

My suggestion is to load your scripts one way, or via wp_enqueue_script or by including in the html header tag. Using both is tricky.

Hope it helps.

Domingos

Comment: Hello. Like I said when I take out the "jquery-1.4.2.js" of the header, then the contact form stops working for some strange reason. I don't get it.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of all the javascript in my header.php at least the ones that call scripts and try to put them in my function.php instead - just like you suggested. However, it seems I'm not implementing the cufon-yui.js correctlz. This is not based on jquery, right? So, I tried the following: `wp_enqueue_script('cufon-yui');`

Comment: The following doesn't work either. I really don't get what I'm doing wrong. Somebody who knows a bit more willing to help?  `wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/custom.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufon-yui.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_register_script('century_font', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Century_Gothic_400-Century_Gothic_700.font.js', array('jquery', 'cufon-yui'));

wp_enqueue_script('custom');
wp_enqueue_script('cufon-yui');
wp_enqueue_script('century-font');`

Comment: Hi, I don't know the cufon-yui but I look it on google and I found that cufon isn't playing nicely with jQuery. You could look into it in http://themocracy.com/2010/01/jquery-cufon-and-wordpress/ and in http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cufon-isn-t-playing-nicely-with-jquery-help. I really hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. You may have some basic syntax issues ( - vs _ vs .), ensuring the correct path/location of the javascript files (have put all the scripts under the 'template_folder/javascript/' and remove all the  calls from header.php

Try this.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    // Load jQuery
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
    wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/custom.js', array('jquery')); wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/cufon-yui.js', array('jquery')); wp_register_script('century-font', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/Century_Gothic_400-Century_Gothic_700.font.js', array('jquery', 'cufon-yui'));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-form');
    wp_enqueue_script('cufon-yui');
    wp_enqueue_script('century-font');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: Hello. I had my js files in two different folders earlier. One was called "js", the other one "javascript", thus the confusion. I put them all into the "js" folder now and also modified the code accordingly. It didn't change a thing.